# I can't serve static images on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to access:

```
http://localhost:3000/images/Header.png
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
Routing Error

No route matches "/images/Header.png" with {:method=>:get}
```

And here are my routes:

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.resources :worker_antpile_statuses

  map.resources :worker_antpiles

  map.resources :antcolonies

  map.resources :antpiles

  map.resources :clients
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last two lines of your `routes.rb` are catch-all routes that will match any previously unmatched URLs.
Comment out those two lines and it will work, which is what you want to do when you use RESTful routing in all your application.

See [this excellent guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for all you need to know about Rails routes.

Comment: That's not enough to serve static files in Rails 3. :(

Answer (score 17):

Static assets need to go in the /public folder or else you'll get the routing error. For a static image at `http://localhost:3000/images/Header.png` you want to place Header.png in `RAILS_ROOT/public/images`

When given any url, Rails will check for a file existing at the path from RAILS_ROOT/public directory before attempting to match any routes.

For example when a Rails server receives a request for `http://localhost:3000/users/1` it will attempt to send the contents of `RAILS_ROOT/public/users/1`. If no file exists, the route matching routine kicks in.

Comment: That works!  THANKS FOR THE HELP.

So what's the purpose of the images folder underneath public?

Comment: Well, I meant anywhere inside /public.  /public/images is fine.  You have an image in /public/images, but it's not loading when you GET its exact address, case sensitive?

Comment: it's the exact address and can't seem to get to the images folder that IS under the public folder.